# How to print typical Json file format into Hashmap(Map) in Scala?

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson

I have written a Scala code where I'm trying to read Json file using fasterxml.jackson package and able read successfully.In the code line number 28 I'm trying to convert Json string into Hashmap(scala) and it is converted but I'm trying the output into systematic format which is given below.

Json file

```
{   "RedDef": [
  {
    "RedDeIn": 2,
    "RedTypC": "XY",
    "RedTypP": ".XY.*$",
    "MinNoOfAt": 19,
    "ExpNoOfAt": 19,
    "RedLen":117,
    "attributes": [
      {
        "AttId": 1,
        "AttNa": "Pro Ty",
        "AttMaxLen": 1,
        "DataTy": {
          "DataName": "AN"
        }
      },
      {
        "AttId": 2,
        "AttNa": "Pro Cod",
        "AttMaxLen": 6,
        "DataTy": {
          "DataName": "AN"
        }
      },
      {
        "AttId": 3,
        "AttNa": "REQ CODE",
        "AttMaxLen": 7,
        "DataTy": {
          "DataName": "AN"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "RedDeIn": 3,
    "RedTypC": "JK",
    "RedTypP": "JK.*$",
    "MinNoOfAt": 10,
    "ExpNoOfAt": 10,
    "attributes": [
      {
        "AttId": 1,
        "AttNa": "Log Si Ty",
        "AttMaxLen": 1,
        "DataTy": {
          "DataName": "A"
        }
      },
      {
        "AttId": 2,
        "AttNa": "Log Si Cod",
        "AttMaxLen": 6,
        "DataTy": {
          "DataName": "AN"
        }
      },
      {
        "AttId": 3,
        "AttNa": "Ex Qu Cod",
        "AttMaxLen": 7,
        "DataTy": {
          "DataName": "AN"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    "RedDeIn": 4,
    "RedTypC": "FK",
    "RedTypP": "FK.*$",
    "MinNoOfAt": 33,
    "ExpNoOfAt": 33,
    "RedLen":117,
    "attributes": [
      {
        "AttId": 1,
        "AttNa": "Pro Ty",
        "AttMaxLen": 1,
        "DataTy": {
          "DataName": "AN"
        }
      },
      {
        "AttId": 2,
        "AttNa": "Pro Cod",
        "AttMaxLen": 6,
        "DataTy": {
          "DataName": "AN"
        }
      },
      {
        "AttId": 3,
        "AttNa": "REQ CDE",
        "AttMaxLen": 7,
        "DataTy": {
          "DataName": "AN"
        }
      },
      {
        "AttId": 4,
        "AttNa": "RED Ty",
        "AttMaxLen": 2,
        "DataTy": {
          "DataName": "AN"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Code

```
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
    import scala.io.Source


    object Json_Parser_Jackson1  {

      case class RecordDefinitions(RedDeIn: Int
                                   ,RedTypC: String
                                   ,RedTypP: String
                                   ,MinNoOfAt: Int
                                   ,ExpNoOfAt: Int
                                   ,RedLen: Int
                                   ,attributes: Seq[Attributes])
      case class Attributes(AttId: Int
                            ,AttNa: String
                            ,AttMaxLen: Int
                            ,dateFormat: Any
                            ,DataTy: DataType)
      case class DataType(DataTyName: String)
      case class Definition(RedDef : Seq[RecordDefinitions])
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val fileContent = Source.fromFile("C:\\kkk\\xxx\\ideaProject\\jsonparser\\src\\main\\resources\\Json_file.json", "UTF-8").getLines.mkString

        val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
        mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
        val testWithMap  = mapper.readValue[Map[_, _]](fileContent)
        println(testWithMap)

      }}
```

Output came from my code like below

```
Map(RedDef -> List(Map(RedTypP -> ^.{14}XY.*$, RedTypC -> XY, ExpNoOfAt -> 19, attributes -> List(Map(AttId -> 1, AttNa -> Pro Ty, AttMaxLen -> 1, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 2, AttNa -> Pro Cod, AttMaxLen -> 6, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 3, AttNa -> REQ CODE, AttMaxLen -> 7, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN))), RedLen -> 117, RedDeIn -> 2, MinNoOfAt -> 19), Map(RedTypP -> ^.{14}JK.*$, RedTypC -> JK, ExpNoOfAt -> 10, attributes -> List(Map(AttId -> 1, AttNa -> Log Si Ty, AttMaxLen -> 1, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> A)), Map(AttId -> 2, AttNa -> Log Si Cod, AttMaxLen -> 6, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 3, AttNa -> Ex Qu Cod, AttMaxLen -> 7, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN))), RedDeIn -> 3, MinNoOfAt -> 10), Map(RedTypP -> ^.{14}FK.*$, RedTypC -> FK, ExpNoOfAt -> 33, attributes -> List(Map(AttId -> 1, AttNa -> Pro Ty, AttMaxLen -> 1, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 2, AttNa -> Pro Cod, AttMaxLen -> 6, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 3, AttNa -> REQ CDE, AttMaxLen -> 7, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN)), Map(AttId -> 4, AttNa -> RED Ty, AttMaxLen -> 2, DataTy -> Map(DataTyName -> AN))), RedLen -> 117, RedDeIn -> 4, MinNoOfAt -> 33)))
```

The output i wanted below like

```
RedTypP = ^.{14}XY.*$
RedTypC = XY
ExpNoOfAt = 19
AttId = 1
AttNa = Pro Ty
AttMaxLen =1
DataTyName = AN
AttId = 2
AttNa = Pro Cod
AttMaxLen = 6
DataName = AN
AttId = 3
AttNa = REQ CODE
AttMaxLen = 7
DataTyName = AN
RedLen = 117
RedDeIn = 2
MinNoOfAt =19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need to beautify the map yourself, something as below, *(I'm using recusion)*

```
val awesomeMap = Map("k1" -> "v1",
  "k2" -> 2,
  "k3" -> 10.28,
  "k4" -> List(Map("k4.k1" -> "v3", "k4.k2" -> List(Map("k4.k3" -> "v4")))))

printInKeyValueFormat(awesomeMap)

def printInKeyValueFormat(givenAMap: Map[String, Any]): Unit = {
  givenAMap foreach {
    case (k: String, v: String) => println(k + "=" + v)
    case (k: String, v: Int) => println(k + "=" + v)
    case (k: String, v: Long) => println(k + "=" + v)
    case (k: String, v: Double) => println(k + "=" + v)
    case (k: String, v: List[Map[String, Any]]) => v.foreach(x => printInKeyValueFormat(x))
  }
}
```

### Output

```
k1=v1
k2=2
k3=10.28
k4.k1=v3
k4.k3=v4
```

You can add more cases if you need.